# Don't include source file in angular dist build

Tags: angular, angular5

In my Angular 5 project I've created an `HttpInterceptor` that should only be used during a debug build, and it just hardcodes some elements like user authentication that I obviously don't want included in the dist build.  Is there a way to have the build process exclude that file?

Comment: You could put all your services in an array and add conditionally HttpInterceptor

Comment: But the code will still be in the compiled bundle, meaning they could find the user/password

Answer (score 0):

You can add your interceptor
only in dev mod

```
const services = [
  /* your list of services*/
  { provide: AUTHENTICATION_SERVICE, useClass: AuthenticationService },
];
if (!environment.production) {
  services.push({ provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, useClass: AuthenticationInterceptor, multi: true })
}
providers:services
```

Comment: But again, this is a runtime configuration item.  The bundled code will still have the authentication service in it, even if it's not being called, right?

Comment: That way you've AuthenticationService but not AuthenticationInterceptor

Comment: You're missing my entire point.  I do not want the file compiled into the bundle at all.  The way you're suggesting I do it the SOURCE code to that AuthenticationInterceptor is still there, meaning somebody can still see the hardcoded username and password.  I realize it won't be *called* but it's still there and searchable.